# How to display largest version number of each document in abap sql?

Tags: abap, opensql

I wish to use below statement to display the largest version number for each of the document, however, the value of DOKVR is blank. Anyone can help?

```
SELECT DOKNR MAX( DOKVR ) FROM DRAT
    WHERE DOKNR IN S_DOKNR
    AND DOKAR IN S_DOKAR.

    WRITE:/ DOKNR, 'H',  DOKVR.
ENDSELECT.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the variables that the data is going into. I believe the following code outputs what you're looking for:

```
DATA: doknr TYPE doknr,
      dokvr TYPE dokvr.
SELECT dokar MAX( dokvr ) FROM drat
  INTO (doknr, dokvr)
  GROUP BY dokar.
  WRITE:/ doknr,'H', dokvr.
ENDSELECT.
```

Output:

```
PTE                       H 21
ITS                       H 09
CMR                       H 04
L01                       H 00
GRI                       H 00
CUM                       H 00
FHD                       H 00
RMS                       H 03
SCE                       H 03
SLD                       H 02
RE                        H 00
GRA                       H 00
(and so on)
```